# Data source name not found Error when connecting app to DB

Tags: odbc, mysql-error-1064, mysql-connector

When I run my asp.net applications I get the following error when connecting to MYSQL DB using connector 8.0 on the server 8.0 versions: **[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified**

My connection string is as follows: 
**"Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Driver};Server=host;Database=dbname;User=myusername;Password=password;Port=3306;Option=3;"**

Usually this error is experienced because of the following

1. there is a mismatch between the installed odbc driver's architecture and the
   application architecture
2. Wrong driver name specified in the connection string
3. A configuration is done at a user level not System level and the app is run by a different user.

I confirmed my app is a 32 bit version and have configured the DNS for a 32 bit system. I have gone through the documentation for setting up the odbc connections and even specified the "Unicode" in the connection string as well as replacing the driver name with the name I used in the odbc setup according to the following recommendation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-programming-net-csharp.html

When using MYSQL 5.xx server version with a 5.xx connector I can connect to the DB using the same applications but fails when I install server 8.0. Unfortunately I need to upgrade to the 8. version to utilise the features such as CTEs and an InnoDB engine with full text search indexes which are missing in 5. versions

Comment: Where you able to solve this problem?

Comment: @PC.I can't say I solved the problem because it logically doesn't make sense how I got it to work. Accidentally I tried connecting with the 5. version connection string replacing the 8.0 with 5.1 {MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver} and it worked. I decided to keep it that way without further investigation as long as it works because this is a project I took over from some old engineer and m already working on replacing. Just in case you want alternatives, in my .Net projects, I use Dapper Adapter and Entity Framework which don't give me odbc problems